# Java Exception Program Tracing

Tags: java, exception

```
public class ExceptionExample3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyExceptionExample3 obj = new MyExceptionExample3();
        try {
            obj.m2();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("main :" + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("main : resume here");
        obj.m2(); // do not catch, terminate abnormally!
        System.out.println("main : do not print this line ….");
    }
}

class MyExceptionExample3 {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("m1 : print this line....");
        // int x=5/0;
        throw new RuntimeException("hello exception from m1()!");
        // do not reach here!
    }

    public void m2() {
        try {
            m1();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("m2 :" + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("m2 : resume here");
        m1(); // catch in main function
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
m1 : print this line....
m2 :hello exception from m1()!
m2 : resume here
m1 : print this line....
main :hello exception from m1()!
main : resume here
m1 : print this line....
m2 :hello exception from m1()!
m2 : resume here
m1 : print this line....
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: hello exception
from m1()
```

This is a example given in class about exceptions. I did not write this program, but I'm having some trouble tracing this exception **example** program. I'm not even sure why exceptions are even being thrown. If someone can please walk me through this program that would be great thank you.

Comment: Throwing exceptions on your own and asking for why they are throwing is not a good thing to do.

Comment: throw new RuntimeException("hello exception from m1()!"); This is the culprit in your program.

Comment: this is always going to throw a exception from  m1, you might want to add a condition for when it should throw the exception

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. This was a in class example of a exception.  I am just having trouble tracing the program and understanding why the exception is needed/ why its being thrown.

Comment: try https://github.com/alfredxiao/jackplay

Answer (score 0):

since you have taken this program from your class, I assume that they are trying to explain propagation of Exception object when they are handled through user defined handler( try and catch block )and when they are given to default Exception Handler(JVM).
1) main method is calling m2 method which is in turn calling m1 method which is handled by user defined handler.
2)m2 method calling m1 method  in here whatever exception object formed is given to its below hierarchy which will catch the Exception object raised in m1 method.
3) main calling m2 method without user defined handler which will go to default exception handler which is jvm.
they are simply demonstrating how Exception object flows in stack hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions get thrown in `m1()` where you have have:

```
throw new RuntimeException("hello exception from m1()!");
```

and then propagate back through the call stack until they can be handled by an appropriate `catch` block. The program generally handles the exception by identifying which method has caught them and then printing the message.

As to the logic, it appears this is merely an academic or abstract example, so the exceptions are being thrown simply to demonstrate how custom exceptions and exception handling can be implemented, and how exceptions affect the flow of a program

The programs comments are decently written so any further explanation feels a little redundant, but for a more complete explanation of exception in general try the [Exceptions Lesson](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).